# How to search backward for substring of string (backword indexOf) starting from specific index

Tags: java

I would like to search for substring of string starting from specific index.

Let's say I have string: `"PO DAD PO PE DA X PO ZA RA"`

Index from which I want to start is character `X`, so is 13. If I would like to search normally for 'ZA' I would do something like:
`"DAD PO PE DA X PO ZA RA ZA".indexOf("ZA")` and I would get 18.

Next I want to search for first substring `'PO'` but backward from `"X"` index. So, I would get 4 (as it is closer to `X` from left side) not 15.

How could I do this?

Comment: Search for `"OP"` in `"X AD EP OP DAD"`.

Comment: @ScottHunter is there any shorter way or more efficient, stirng will be so much longer than in example.

Comment: How do you know you *need* it to be more efficient?  (Don't know what you mean by "shorter".)

Comment: @ScottHunter but wait, if I would search for OP in your example I would get: 8 not 4. You misunderstood. I want to get index of PO from whole string (but starting looking from X). So PO starts from 4 index (but it is first occurence of this substring from left side of X). So it works like indexOf but from left, not from right.

Comment: I think your use of the word `backward` is somehow confusing. Which substring / index would you like to get if the input was `"DAD PO PE PO X PO ZA"` and why?

Comment: @Eritrean If I would search for 'PO' I would like to get 10 as it is closer to X, but the index is taken from whole string.

Comment: And if there is no substring, which have an index lower than index of `X` you want to get the greater index? For example `"DAD PP PP PP X PO ZA"` a search for `"PO"` should return 15, did I get it right?

Comment: @Eritrean there always will be such a substring, so dont have to think about such a situation

Comment: I did not misunderstand; once you know the location in the reversed string, it is a simple matter to compute the corresponding location in the original string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "PO DAD PO PE DA X PO ZA RA";
    System.out.println(usingSubstring(s));

    
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        usingSubstring(s);
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("`usingSubstring()` took " + (end - start) + "ms.");
}


/**
 * 1. Get the first index of `X`.
 * 2. Substring from 0 ... (1).
 * 3. Get the last index from (2) for `PO`.
 *
 * @param s input string
 * @return last index of `PO` backwards from `X`
 */
private static int usingSubstring(String s) {
    String toSearch = "PO";
    String searchUntil = "X";
    return s.substring(0, s.indexOf(searchUntil)).lastIndexOf(toSearch);
}
```

Outputs:

```
7
`usingSubstring()` took 2ms.
```

---

As pointed out by [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger), there's an even simpler way to achieve this using [String#lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)).

```
String s = "PO DAD PO PE DA X PO ZA RA";
System.out.print(s.lastIndexOf("PO", s.indexOf("X")));    // 7
```

Comment: your way is the cleneast and the easiest. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public static int indexOfFromBackOf(String s,String match){
   for(int i = s.length()-1; i>0;i--) {
     int prevI = i;
     boolean found = true;
     for(int j=match.length()-1;j>0 && i>0;j--){
       if(s.charAt(i)!=match.charAt(j)) {found = false; break;}
       else i--;
     }
     if(found) return i;
     i = prevI;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

and then:

```
  String s = "DAD PO PE DA X PO ZA RA ZA";
  String match = "PO"; 
  System.out.println(indexOfFromBackOf(s.substring(0,s.indexOf("X")-1),match));
```

But its messy and complex. why not using Scott's method?
in one line:

```
    String s = "DAD PO PE DA X PO ZA RA ZA";
    String match = "PO";
    String cropped = s.substring(0,s.indexOf("X")-1;
    int index = cropped.length() - (new StringBuilder(cropped).reverse().indexOf(new StringBuilder(match).reverse().toString()) + match.length()));
```

Comment: One line != not complex.

Comment: Can you please also link scott's method for readers who're unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @HarshalParekh see the fisrt comment of the question

Comment: Comments are prone to get deleted over time. It is also unnecessarily expensive. Like the OP has mentioned in another comment: `it looks like completely different and has around 50k of characters`. In the worst case, the cropped could be 50K characters and match could be 49.9K characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a custom `Iterator` for backward search within a `String`. This, not only will allow you to iterate your `String` backward, but it will also tell you whether there are further matches or not (via `hasNext()`) and retrieve all of them with the `next()` method. The class could contain 3 fields: the string to search, the string to look for and an internal cursor. Through the constructor, you could set the two strings (obviously) and the starting point of the `Iterator`'s cursor.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
class StringBackwardSearcher implements Iterator<Integer> {
    private String str, match;
    private int index;

    public BackwardSearcher(String str, String match, int index) {
        this.str = Objects.requireNonNull(str);
        this.match = Objects.requireNonNull(match);
        this.index = Objects.checkIndex(index, str.length());
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = Objects.checkIndex(index, str.length());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return str.substring(0, index).contains(match);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        for (; index >= 0; index--) {
            if (str.substring(index - match.length(), index).equals(match)) {
                Integer temp = index;
                index--;
                return temp - match.length();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Your main would simply consist of

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "PO DAD PO PE DA X PO ZA RA";
    StringBackwardSearcher bs = new StringBackwardSearcher(s, "PO", 16);
    while (bs.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(bs.next());
    }
}
```

If the iterator started at the index of `X` and had to look for `PO`, then the output would be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To throw another solution into the mix, one could compile a regular expression with following logic: match starting with "PO", not followed by "PO", and terminated by "X".

In this way, only the closest (from left side) "PO" would match until an "X".

For example:

```java
String subj = "AA PO DAD PO PE DA X PO ZA RA ZA";
        
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(PO)([^P]|P(?!O))*(X)");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(subj);
if (matcher.find()) {
   System.err.println("match at [" + matcher.start() + "," + matcher.end() + "): " + matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: but  this string was just an example it looks like completely different and has around 50k of characters, so this solution would not work.

Comment: @vig2004, yes of course, this is just the idea: start with A, not followed by A and ending with B. The "not followed by" part is usually the tricky part, but in many common cases we can come up with a regular expression. This solution is of course not so generic as the others.